# Qual é o seletor CSS pra alterar uma determinada classe pai somente se ela tiver uma determinada classe filha

Tags: css, css3

Tenho a seguinte estrutura no HTML:

```html
<div class="panel">
     ...
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <div class="controls"> 
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

A classe `panel` tem alguns estilos gerais e eu gostaria de alterar o `padding-right` dela apenas quando ela contiver como filha a classe `controls`.

Sei que se fosse ao contrário, se quisesse alterar a classe `controls` só se ela fosse filha de `panel`, o seletor no CSS ficaria:

```css
.panel .controls {
  ...
}
```

Ou:

```css
.panel > .controls {
   ...
}
```

Mas e para alterar a classe `panel` só se ela tiver como filha a classe `controls`? Existe seletor pra isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atualmente (maio/2021) não é possível fazer isso com CSS.

Existe [esta proposta](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo) para o pseudo-seletor `:has`. Com ele seria possível ter algo como:

```css
/* seleciona os elementos com a classe panel, mas só se tiver filho com a classe control */
.panel:has(> .controls) {
    estilos...
}
```

Mas isso ainda [**não é suportado pelos browsers**](https://caniuse.com/css-has). Ou seja, por enquanto não tem como fazer com CSS, então uma alternativa seria recorrer ao JavaScript. Ex:

```js
// para todos os elementos com class=panel
for (const elemento of document.querySelectorAll('.panel')) {
    // verifica se tem controls dentro do elemento, e aplica um estilo diferente para cada caso
    if (elemento.querySelector('.controls')) { // tem
        elemento.style.color = "yellow";
    } else { // não tem
        elemento.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

```css
.panel {
  /* será sobrescrito pelo JavaScript */
  color: blue;
}

.panel .controls {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
     verde
</div>

<div class="panel">
    amarelo
    <div class="controls"> 
       vermelho
    </div>
</div>
```